# Why can't you modify the data returned by a Mongoose Query (ex: findById)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I try to change any part of the data returned by a Mongoose Query it has no effect.

I was trying to figure this out for about 2 hours yesterday, with all kinds of `_.clone()`s, using temporary storage variables, etc. Finally, just when I though I was going crazy, I found a solution. So I figured somebody in the future (fyuuuture!) might have the save issue.

```
Survey.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
    var len = data.survey_questions.length;
    var counter = 0;

    _.each(data.survey_questions, function(sq){
        Question.findById(sq.question, function(err, q){
            sq.question = q; //has no effect

            if(++counter == len) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you turn a Mongoose document into a plain object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503450/how-do-you-turn-a-mongoose-document-into-a-plain-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9952649/4748042

Answer (score 180, accepted):

For cases like this where you want a plain JS object instead of a full model instance, you can call [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on the query chain like so:

```
Survey.findById(req.params.id).lean().exec(function(err, data){
    var len = data.survey_questions.length;
    var counter = 0;

    _.each(data.survey_questions, function(sq){
        Question.findById(sq.question, function(err, q){
            sq.question = q;

            if(++counter == len) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way `data` is already a plain JS object you can manipulate as you need to.

Comment: Btw @JohnnyHK just wanted to say thanks again. A year and a half later was helping a client debug something. He spent a weekend trying to figure something out, turns out it was because he was trying to modify the Mongoose Object ;P

Comment: 2 years later and still crushing it.  Didn't even realize lean() was there.

Comment: When using `findOne`, I can just modify the object and then call `data.save()` which seems to work just fine (I'm appending to an array)

Comment: What about when using `aggregate` instead of a simple `find`?

Comment: @Fizzix `aggregate` always provides its results as plain objects, so there's no need for `lean()`.

Comment: 3 years later and spent and entire hour trying to figure it out.
Saved my whole day! Thanks

Comment: and you will loose all virtual method magic with this approach.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, but why is it impossible to modify the object? What kind of special object is it?

Answer (score 50):

I think the Mongoose documentation doesn't make this clear enough, but the data returned in the query (although you can res.send() it) is actually a Mongoose Document object, and NOT a JSON object. But you can fix this with one line...

```
Survey.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
    var len = data.survey_questions.length;
    var counter = 0;

    var data = data.toJSON(); //turns it into JSON YAY!

    _.each(data.survey_questions, function(sq){
        Question.findById(sq.question, function(err, q){
            sq.question = q;

            if(++counter == len) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can also use [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject), which does the same thing as `toJSON()` but with a less confusing name.

Comment: Will this also get rid of virtuals put on by the developer as well?

Comment: `TypeError: data.toObject is not a function` I got this, same with `toJSON`

Comment: Instead of modifying the `result`, I was able to modify `result._doc`.

Comment: @Luzan Baral Thats because you are using these function for Array object. Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` instead for Arrays of object

Comment: @mohit thank u so much for the tip. It saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I was using mongoose and here are the workaround I did to resolve it:

1):
Mongoose returns MongooseDocument objects and not plain JSON objects. So use the lean() method on object which will convert it into JSON, and from there you can change it

```
const leanDoc = await MyModel.findOne().lean();
```

---------------------------------OR---------------------------------

2): Create a deep copy of the result returned by find query as shown below

```
Books.find({}).then(books => { 
    books = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(books));
    //now you can update the books object
}
```