# Is Mongoose query result read-only?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I modify an object returned by a Mongoose query?

Assume we have the following schema:

```
var S = new mongoose.Schema( { 'name': String, 'field': String } );
```

I do the following query and modification to the result:

```
var retrieve = function(name, callback) {
    S.findOne({ name: name }).exec(function (err, obj) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      obj['field'] = 'blah';
      callback(obj);
    });
}
```

The `obj.field` will not contain `blah` but the original value returned by the query, as if it was read-only. What is going on?

Note: my environment is Node.js, Express, Mongoose and MongoDB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't you modify the data returned by a Mongoose Query (ex: findById)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This is an edit, my original answer was rather different

So this is a little confusing but **Mongoose returns MongooseDocument objects and not plain JSON objects**. So use the .lean() method on obj which will turn it into JSON, and from there you start altering it as you wish.

With thanks to Ze Jibe.

Comment: Thanks Niall, but does not fix the issue: `obj`still unchanged. I should also precise that I don't want to update the object in the DB, but simply use a copy of it that I can modify for other purposes. I've tried copying the `obj` to `cpy`and modify `cpy` but I'm left with the same problem, that `cpy`seems also to be read-only

Comment: hmm is there any reason you went with .exec over `S.findOne({name: name}, function (err,obj) { .. })`?

Comment: hmm odd, I'm literally just throwing things out there now. what happens where ever callback(obj) is? like is it 'read-only' then? Sounds very odd that it'd be read only. you've me intrigued

Comment: callback(obj) is a `res.send(obj)`, so I can see in my browser what the content of `obj` is. I've also put `console.log()` around the `obj['field'] = 'blah'` command, and both before and after the command the `obj` content is the same (as printed in the console). I'm clueless...

Comment: you know where you have res.send(obj)? Could you throw a quick `obj['field'] = 'blah';` just to check if its okay then? Might give a hint..

Answer (score 2):

The *doc* object returned from mongoose is somehow read only. To get a writeable object from it you must run:

```
var writeableObject = doc.toObject()
writeableObject['field'] = 'blah'
res.send(writeableObject)
```

Scroll down to "Transform" in the mongoose documentation to read more: [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js)