# Express JS + Mongoose with different csv modules sends wrong data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm using this module: https://github.com/nulltask/express-csv
(also tried a couple more)

```
       MyModel.find(mquery,function(err, list){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                var response = {
                    success: false,
                    data: null
                };
                res.json(response);
            }else{
                console.log(list);
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=mylist.csv');
                res.csv(list);
            }
        });
```

The problem is what is rendered in the csv file.
It is Mongoose's Model itself. But on the console logs the actual data.

Any hints?

**Update**

Apparently static JSON data it is rendered in the CSV file, so must be something with syncing....

Comment: How do you see the console logs? from your code it will only console.log if there is an error..

Comment: I left it out. And add it back after edit.

Comment: Is the csv you are writing complicated or something? It's quite easy to write such csv file on your own without any external library. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zcsmnzy6/ I created this module for a project i worked on and it outputted data from a mongoose find query without any issues...

Comment: I was just writing a similar solution.
Unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: The way i used the callback is as follows: 

router.get('/export', function (req, res) {
 api.getUsers().then(function (result) {
  var csv = helpers.convertToCsv(result);
  res.header('content-type', 'text/csv');
  res.header('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=contactus.csv');
  res.write(csv);
  res.end();
 });
})

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyTordgeman, but it seems that is something else.
I still get the 'Document'  API from Mongoose instead the data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'document' api? can you add to the question the full function code? the output of the csv?

Comment: Having the same issue. Especially evident with @JohnnyTordgeman 's fiddle. The mongoose query callback returns a bizarre object that the docs don't mention, right now it is like it's full of ghost keys holding functions that get printed

Comment: Oh, not an object, returns Document and that's the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504387/3366809

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose query returns a Document, not a simple object, despite not stating that clearly in their docs (stackoverflow.com/a/14504387/3366809). This confounds express-csv or anything trying to loop over it. Use lean() in the query to return an object instead of a Document.

```
var myquery = MyModel.find(mquery);
myquery.lean().exec(function(err, list) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    var response = {
      success : false,
      data : null
    };
    res.json(response);
  } else {
    console.log(list);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=mylist.csv');
    res.csv(list);
  }
});
```