# Add a new property to Mongoose Document after fetch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with understanding the variable manipulation in JavaScript. 
Following code:

```
UserScore.find(filter, function (err, userScores) {
  var contests = [];
  userScores.forEach(function(userScore)
  {
    contests.push(userScore.ContestId);
  });
  Contest.find({ '_id': { $in : contests } }, function(err, contestItems)
  {
    var result = [];

    contestItems.forEach(function(con)
    {
      userScores.forEach(function(element) {
        if(element.ContestId == con._id)
        {
          con.UserTeamName = element.TeamName;
          con.UserPersonalScore = element.Score;
          console.log(con);
          console.log(con.UserPersonalScore);
          result.push(con);
          return;
        }
      });
    });
    res.status(200).json(result);
  });
});
```

prints "con" without the two added properties, and prints "con.UserPersonalScore" with the appropriate value. When pushed to result, con does not have additional properties. What am I missing?

I guess I am somehow creating local variables instead of properties, but why isn't it being pushed to the result array?

Comment: You need to provide a test case that actually demonstrates the problem — http://sscce.org/ — you're manipulating a lot of variables (this can probably be simplified), but not showing us how they are defined, and you're making claims about what the value of `con` in `result` is without showing us how you are determining that.

Comment: Please writer complete json or object structure of con

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any JSON here either. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong snippet, that "this" was just an experiment. xd

Comment: @BarthZalewski that does not help.

Comment: @Quentin I edited my question and inserted a wider part of code, hope it helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON whatsoever, except that the end result is translated to JSON.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I thought that JSONs are returned from the database (MongoDB)

Comment: The object read from the MongoDB is supposed to be in frozen state. You might not be able to mutate it.

Comment: @TaoP.R. That is right! Thanks a lot! Thanks to your comment I found this question: [Why can't you modify the data returned by a Mongoose Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid) and using `lean()` did the trick. Can you post an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Object returned from Mongodb query is in frozen (immutable) state**

Your code seems to interact with MongoDB. The object returned is actually a Mongodb model instance, not a plain javascript object. You can't modify the object returned from a query.

**To convert the Mongodb document to a JSON object**

[`.toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) does the trick. It converts a frozen MongoDB document to a JSON object.

Comment: Workaround: [How to get a plain JS object that can be manipulated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid) .

Comment: I also update it with a reference to `.toObject()` since nobody mentioned it in the thread yet. Hope it's helpful to people who came across this too.

Comment: *to a JS object. JSON is a string structure.