# Can't get property of objects I've created. Looks like problems with mongoose for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

*UPD. PROBLEM SOLVED WITH ONE LINE OF CODE: 
**.lean()**
[axplanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid)*

I have this array of menu items after Model.find(...blablabla :

```
[ 
{"_id":"578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8", 
"text":"lists", "iconCls":"fa fa-group fa-lg", 
"className":null, 
"menu_id":null},
```

{"_id":"578762146e8e0542195ef4e7", 
"iconCls":"fa fa-group fa-lg",
"className":"panel", 
"menu_id":"578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8",
 "text":"personal"},

{"_id":"578770aca59f4d173c948376", 
"text":"info", 
"iconCls":"xf007",
 "className":null, 
"menu_id":null},

{"_id":"5787715aa59f4d173c94837c", 
"text":"cars", 
"className":"panel",
 "menu_id":"578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8", "iconCls":"xf007"},

{"_id":"5787721ca59f4d173c94837f", 
"text":"now" ,
"iconCls":"xf007",
 "className":"xf007", 
"menu_id":"578770aca59f4d173c948376"}]

And I want to build tree menu from them:

```
function buildMenu(source){    
    var menu = []; //Массив для нового, уже пирамидального меню        
    for (var i=0; i<source.length; i+=1){
        if(source[i].menu_id === null){ //Выбираем верхние пункты меню
            source[i].items = [];
            for(var j=0; j<source.length;j+=1){
                if(source[j].menu_id !== null){
                    if(source[i]._id.toString() == source[j].menu_id.toString()){
                        //найден дочерний пункт меню
                        source[i].items.push(source[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            menu.push(source[i]);
        }
    }
    // Проверка
    console.log(menu[0].items);
    console.log(menu);
    return menu;
}
```

So, when I trying to console.log my menu[0].items - I have them:

```
[ { _id: 578762146e8e0542195ef4e7,
    iconCls: 'fa fa-group fa-lg',
    className: 'panel',
    menu_id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
    text: 'personal' },
  { _id: 5787715aa59f4d173c94837c,
    text: 'cars',
    className: 'panel',
    menu_id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
    iconCls: 'xf007' } ]
```

But then, when I trying to return my new amazing menu, I get this:

```
[ { _id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
    text: 'lists',
    iconCls: 'fa fa-group fa-lg',
    className: null,
    menu_id: null },
  { _id: 578770aca59f4d173c948376,
    text: 'info',
    iconCls: 'xf007',
    className: null,
    menu_id: null } ]
```

My God! Where is my items dissapeared!?!

Upd. I expecting to get something like this:

```
[ { _id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
    text: 'lists',
    iconCls: 'fa fa-group fa-lg',
    className: null,
    menu_id: null 
    items: [ 
         { _id: 578762146e8e0542195ef4e7,
         iconCls: 'fa fa-group fa-lg',
         className: 'panel',
         menu_id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
         text: 'personal' },
         { _id: 5787715aa59f4d173c94837c,
         text: 'cars',
         className: 'panel',
         menu_id: 578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8,
         iconCls: 'xf007' } 
     ]       
      .....
```

Here is how I get my data:

```
.get('/menu', function(req,res){        

        var user_id = '5784b872a59f4d0f805a617d'; //пользователь boss/boss
        User.find({_id:user_id})
            .populate({
                path: 'group',
                populate: {
                    path: 'menu',
                    ref: 'Menu'
                }
            })
            .exec(function(err,user) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.red, req.method, req.url);
                    res.status(500).end();
                    return err;
                } else if (!user) {
                    res.status(404).end();
                    console.log(('Запрос вернул: ' + user).red);
                } else {
                    res.status(200).send(buildMenu(user[0].group.menu));
                }
            });
        //
    })
```

**MENUS:**

[image]

**USERS:**

[image]

**GROUPES:**

[image]

**I am realy confused...**

[image]

**Postman cant see them also:**

[image]

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: What you want to return and what you are getting the result..Can you please clarify with proper data @antonPegov

Comment: You mean that the `items` property is missing in the console.log output? It's likely only missing in the display used. Can you zoom in on the object in the browser? Also depending on the browser, you could try `console.dir` instead of console.log to test the full object or use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I get the array of menu from mongoDB database, then sending the result with node.js to the browser. In browser console I also can't see my items:       [link]http://joxi.ru/EA4K73BUqYQq2b

Comment: Yes, it is problem beacose of Mongoose, still investigaying...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the tree with an object for look up and for creating the tree with random source order.

```js
var source = [{ "_id": "578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8", "text": "lists", "iconCls": "fa fa-group fa-lg", "className": null, "menu_id": null }, { "_id": "578762146e8e0542195ef4e7", "iconCls": "fa fa-group fa-lg", "className": "panel", "menu_id": "578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8", "text": "personal" }, { "_id": "578770aca59f4d173c948376", "text": "info", "iconCls": "xf007", "className": null, "menu_id": null }, { "_id": "5787715aa59f4d173c94837c", "text": "cars", "className": "panel", "menu_id": "578763de6e8e0542195ef4e8", "iconCls": "xf007" }, { "_id": "5787721ca59f4d173c94837f", "text": "now", "iconCls": "xf007", "className": "xf007", "menu_id": "578770aca59f4d173c948376" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.items = o[a._id] && o[a._id].items;
            o[a._id] = a;
            if (a.menu_id === root) {
                r.push(a);
            } else {
                o[a.menu_id] = o[a.menu_id] || {};
                o[a.menu_id].items = o[a.menu_id].items || [];
                o[a.menu_id].items.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(source, null);

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: snks! I think the problem is beacose I using mongoose objects to deal with mongoDB data. Youre code is working in plain node.js, but not working inside my app (

Comment: is your data sorted? i meand are the parents first?

Comment: no, [link] http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/07/19/0018/3922/1191762/62/43c28a413f.png

Comment: you yould use a `for` loop instead of `forEach` if that helps.

Comment: I've tryed I think everything... I've updated my post with database screens.