# Mongoose return entair object and some elements in array which matched some requirements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a object in mongodb. I want to filter their sections using status. If status is `active` then only that has to be sent to the user.

Structure of the Course schema is:

```
{
   _id: 'ObjectId',
   name: 'NODE JS',
   .
   .
   sections: [
      {status: 'active', trainer: 'XYZ'}, {status: 'inactive', trainer: 'YZX'}, .....
   ]
}
```

below `'sections.status': 'active'` is working properly for filtering the courses but it is returning all the sections which are not active. How can I filter the array in mongoose query itself. Without handling the query results.

```
Course.findOne({ _id: req.params.id , 'sections.status': 'active' })
  .exec((err, course) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error in getting data' });
    } else if (!course) {
      res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'No course details found' });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: true, course });
    }
  });
```

Comment: You want the response to contain all the data from the schema with the only difference being that that the inactive `sections` are removed?

Comment: @Mike Yes. What you said is true.

Comment: I don't believe that you can remove data from a document using Mongoose without writing to the database itself. I think you said you didn't want to do this in your answer but the best you're likely able to do is manually remove items from `sections` that are inactive and send the modified object in the response instead.

See here for a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have Mongoose return a modified document for you without writing it to the database. However, you can use the `lean` function to have Mongoose return an object literal, without the added overhead of the full model itself, and modify that object as you wish to send with your data.

```
Course.findOne({ _id: req.params.id , 'sections.status': 'active' })
  .lean()
  .exec((err, course) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error in getting data' });
    } else if (!course) {
      res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'No course details found' });
    } else {

      // Remove all 'inactive' sections
      course.sections = course
                          .sections
                          .filter((section) => section.status === 'active')

      res.json({ success: true, course });
    }
  });
```

See the following post for a reference.

[Why can't you modify the data returned by a Mongoose Query (ex: findById)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid)

Comment: Thak you. Till now I was using promises to filter it because I'm not aware of lean() method.