# Delete operator not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

This is a function that removes sensitive information from a JSON object before it gets returned to the client. The data that's being passed into the function would either be a JSON object or an array of JSON objects. Why would this function not work?

I know that there are other solutions to the problem, but this is annoying my brain.

I have logged plenty of information in this function and even though JavaScript is asynchronous the functions are running in the order that they should - the recursion is finishing before the final return statement is hit.

The issue right now is that even though everything seems to be working and the `delete` operator is returning `true`, the attributes being deleted are still present when the function finally returns.

Example `data` which is being fetched from MongoDB:

```
[
    {
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'John',
        'password': 'test123',
        'emailAddress': 'john@example.com',
        'emailAddressVerificationCode': 'A897D'
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'Andrew',
        'password': 'test123',
        'emailAddress': 'andrew@example.com',
        'emailAddressVerificationCode': '90H8D'
    },
    {
        'id': '3',
        'name': 'Matthew',
        'password': 'test123',
        'emailAddress': 'matthew@example.com',
        'emailAddressVerificationCode': '56C7C'
    }
]
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
UserService.cleanJSON = (data) => {

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            data[i] = UserService.cleanJSON(data[i]);
        }
    } else {

        if (data.password) delete data.password;
        if (data.emailAddressVerficationCode) delete data.emailAddressVerficationCode;
        if (data.mobileNumberVerificationCode) delete data.mobileNumberVerificationCode;
        if (data.accountType) delete data.accountType;
    }


    return data;
};
```

Comment: Can you supply an example initialization of `data` for which it does not work?

Comment: Also, `probably` not related to your issue, but there's probably no need to return `data` from the function since it is editing the original object passed in by reference.

Comment: This function will work as intended. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @anied the reason for the return is for the recursion. In the for loop its setting the array elements.

Comment: @JonathanGilbert I'll edit the question now.

Comment: "*still present when the function finally returns*" - how do you know? Did you immediately `JSON.stringify` it? Notice that your function doesn't create a new object, it preserves the reference to passed one, so possibly some other code in your application restores the information.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, if I log the `data`, even immediately after the delete statements, the attributes are still present.

Comment: @Schlaus - Even logging `data` immediately before and after the `delete` statement is not removing the attribute despite the `delete` returning true.

Comment: Is this line a typo? `if (data.emailAddressVerficationCode) delete data.emailAddressVerficationCode;` Verfication instead of Verification. Other than that, it works fine for me in the Chrome console.

Comment: Are using Mongoose? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid

Comment: @MezoIstvan, yes that's a typo. Whoops!

Comment: When I run the code, it removes the `password` property, so @MezoIstvan has it right.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I am using Mongoose. This is every interesting! I will run some tests now.

Comment: @nickcorin -- yes, but even in this scenario it will be editing those objects on the original object-- still all being passed by reference.  Not really a problem, per se-- I just think it is unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, you were right. The issue was with trying to edit data from Mongoose. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using Mongoose or any other ODM, right?
If so, you have to know that you can not change the results unless you call the method `.lean()`  (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).

Mongoose keeps the model safe from any modifications unless you detach the result.

Comment: This worked! Never knew this about Mongoose. Thank you! Thanks to @JohnnyHK too for leading me to this answer.

Comment: In fact, you should always use .lean() if you know for sure that you are not going to change the model resulting from the query; You´ll spend much less memory and increase performance as the objects will be much lighter. Another tip would be to use projections so you don´t get any values from the database that you are not going to use.

Comment: I will do from now on. Is there a way to use lean without having to use the `.exec()` syntax for the callback but rather the callback syntax that was used in my example?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the comma after the last curly bracket in your JSON.

Comment: This was a typo in the question. In the application the data is being fetched from MongoDB and will not have these errors.