# Convert "Binary Data" Image in Mongoose/MongoDB to base64 and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I uploaded an image to mongoose and the it was saved as a binary data like so:

[image]

Now Im trying to retrieve that image and display within my HTML page like so:

```
 <img id="user-img" src="data:image/png;base64, {{base64String}}">
```

**I have tried the following:**

I am trying to convert the binary image server side before sending the user all the data.

```
let getOne = (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            data.photo = new Buffer(data.photo.toString(), 'base64');
             sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data)
        } else if (!data) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "Unable to find a single user"})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)
    })
  };
```

**At this point the server crashes and gives a `Internal Server Error 500`**

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: @RolandStarke see updated question for an image of the error received.

Comment: @RolandStarke hi, please see updated question for console logged error.

Comment: Ah okay. so photo is not defined. don't as me why :D

Comment: When you got your photo you can get rid of `new Buffer(data.photo.toString(), 'base64');` I assume  photo  is already a buffer so: `var base64OfPhoto = data.photo.toString('base64')` is enough.

Comment: @RolandStarke thanks. I’ll try that now. I noticed something weird though. I uploaded a new image to mongoose and now it’s returning the image in base64 automatically. This has happened before as well. After a while it starts returning binary data instead of base64. Any idea why?

Comment: maybe your old images where saved differently? Else maybe `data.photo = ` has no effect like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510823/5378743

Comment: @RolandStarke apologies for the late reply. The weird thing is both times the data was saved exactly the same way. I just uploaded another image and now it’s returning pure base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `.exec()` part. The exec runs and returns the data but `then` is expecting a promise.

```
User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
```

Should work.